# How can i solve the @a.Message following problem?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
@foreach (var a in Model.MESSAGES.OrderBy(p => p.DATE))
{
    var id = a.SENDERID == ViewBag.KullaniciId ? a.SENTID : a.SENDERID;
    var name = Model.USERS.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == id)?.NAMESURNAME;
    <tr id="tr@(a.ID)">
        <td>@name</td>
        <td>@a.MESSAGE.Substring(0, Math.Min(100, a.MESSAGE.Length))</td>
    </tr>
}
```

I get the following error :

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> CoreFramework.Entities.Concrete.MEESAGES.Message.get returned null.

Comment: You need to check if there is any value in `@a.MESSAGE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [null conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

```
<td>@a.MESSAGE?.Substring(0, Math.Min(100, a.MESSAGE.Length))</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [null-conditional-operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

```cs
<td>@a.MESSAGE?.Substring(0, Math.Min(100, a.MESSAGE.Length))</td>
```